# Concatenation of column vectors below one another through loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I want to concatenate column vectors below one another in an excel sheet through MATLAB. I have the following code:

```
  g1 = cell2mat(rmse_h1);
  c1 = g1';
  g2 = cell2mat(rmse_h2);
  c2 = g2';
  g3 = cell2mat(rmse_h3);
  c3 = g3';
```

Here, rmse_h1,rmse_h2 and rmse_h3 are 3 different row vectors with 16 values in each. I am converting this row vector into column vector by taking transpose such as c1,c2,c3.

Now my question is I want to concatenate c1,c2 and c3 below one another in a single column of excel sheet such as:
c2 comes under c1 and c3 comes under c2

I want to do this for a total of 10 different row vectors. I want to use for loop in MATLAB how can i do this ?? Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: You have 10 such `rmse_h` vectors. You're converting into 10 such `g` vectors and then 10 such `c` vectors and then you want to combine them into one. ***NO***. Please modify whatever code has brought you to this and do not create dynamic variables.

Comment: I have a very big code i am using here only a small code. I can simplify my question that if have 10 different column vector how can i concatenate them  below one another using for loop and write them in a single column in excel sheet

Comment: Use cell arrays, `g{1}` instead of a new variable `g1` etc... then concatenation is as easy as `vertcat(g{:})`... Read about creating a [mcve], and if this part of the question has nothing to do with Excel then limit the scope of the question specifically to the concatenation, or handling of variables.

Comment: @AhmadBilal How do you generate your `rmse_h*` data? As I mention in the comments below, it would be much easier to restructure your code so that these variables are grouped into an array of some sort, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation is easy as `[c1 ; c2 ; c3]`

As other people mentioned, using a cell array will be a great idea. Then use `vertcat` to finalize the job.

My solution is using a `struct` to better manage your data.

Let's say you have an undefined number of variables `g1,g2,g3...g99`
So after conversion, you get `c1 = g1'` (or simply `c1 = g1(:)`), and such such...
The best practice here is to use a `struct` data type

First I would define a struct variable to store your imported excel data

```
C = [];
n = 100; % Number of sheets. Let's assume you know this.
for idx = 1:n
    fileds = sprintf('rmse_h%d',idx);
    d.(field) = readtable(filename, FileType','spreadsheet' ,'Sheet','1);  
    C = [C ; table2array(d.(field))];
end
```

Now you can loop through each field in `d` if you would like to format the data in other ways.

Comment: I disagree. To me, `d.rmse_h1` is no better than `rmse_h1`. First, fields in a struct imply heterogeneous data (even if the data is of the same *type*). Since the OP is combining all of the `rmse_h*` instances, they must be homogeneous. This also makes it no easier to iterate over the data instances. A *slightly* better approach using structs would be to store the data in a struct array like `rmse_h(i).data`. While that still perpetuates the (in my mind) incorrect thinking that different instances of the same data require different variables, it at least makes it easier to access the data.

Comment: We also don't know that the OP is *reading* from an excel file. The first thing their code does is convert a cell array to a matrix, so it's reasonable to assume that `rmse_h1` starts off as a cell array as opposed to a table or a matrix (returned by `readtable` and `xlsread`, respectively). If those cell array variables were *generated* as `rmse_h{1}`, `rmse_h{2}` and `rmse_h{3}` instead of `rmse_h1`, `rmse_h2` and `rmse_h3`, it would be a trivial matter to iterate over all of the data or to concatenate it, e.g. `C = horzcat(rmse_h{:}).'`.

Comment: Respect your opinion. My solution simply pointed to a thought which might be suitable for a type of data management perspective. The OP did mention Excel sheet. In my opinion, data imported from an excel or a tabular format is easy to be managed with either `table`, `struct`, or both, depending on situations. In the case of data processing, I would think of `table`, or `cell`; otherwise, if the imported data need to retain some meta information, `struct` could be a good solution for its versatile usage.

Comment: @beaker I don't think my solution was bad and it might as well suitable in the OP's need. I believe we both agree that the OP didn't ask the question well. So I don't think we have to go on discussion from this point. I also suggest you wirte down a solution and a rationale to your solution so the OP may select you as the best answer?